# How can I retrieve all variants only for a specific gene from VCF file using BCFTools?

Tags: bioinformatics, bcftools

I have downloaded the complete vcf file for human genome (GRCh38) from [clinvar](https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/clinvar/vcf_GRCh38/). I want to filter all the variants only for TP53 gene. For now, I have used the following Linux command. Could anyone please let me know how I can achieve this same results using bcftools?

```
zcat clinvar.vcf.gz | awk ' { if (substr($1,1,1) == "#" ) print $0 }' > only_tp53.vcf
zcat clinvar.vcf.gz | grep "GENEINFO=TP53:" >> only_tp53.vcf
```

I took the genomic coordinates for TP53 from [NCBI/Gene database](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/7157) and tried the following command, but it's not retrieving all the variants; few are missing.

```
bcftools view -r 17:7668421-7687490 clinvar.vcf.gz > clinvar_tp53_variants.vcf
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what is missed?

Comment: Perhaps you're finding 'TP53 modifiers', e.g. variants in regions outside the TP53 gene that are annotated with the word TP53 e.g. MDM2, MDM4, CDKN2A are in the TP53 pathway, and specific variants in these genes can be annotated with the word "TP53" despite not occuring within 17:7668421-7687490. If you could please provide some examples of 'missing' TP53 variants it might help figure out the problem

Comment: Thank you @jared_mamrot for pointing out the issue correctly. Yes, all the additional variants are located in TP53 modifier region (outside TP53 gene; either upstream or downstream). Here is an examples 

```17 7667874 925574 G C . . ALLELEID=914159;CLNDISDB=MONDO:MONDO:0015356,MeSH:D009386,MedGen:C0027672,Orphanet:140162;CLNDN=Hereditary_cancer-predisposing_syndrome;CLNHGVS=NC_000017.11:g.7667874G>C;CLNREVSTAT=criteria_provided,_single_submitter;CLNSIG=Likely_benign;CLNVC=single_nucleotide_variant;CLNVCSO=SO:0001483;GENEINFO=TP53:7157;ORIGIN=1;RS=1049800949```

Comment: You're welcome @JoshuaJebaraj. For future reference, this type of question isn't really [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow, as it's not really about writing software or programming. It is much better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/, and I've found that the community there is very helpful with these kinds of "I'm having trouble using a bioinformatics program" questions. Nevertheless, I'm glad you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

TP53 is "chr17:7668421-7687490" ( https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hg38&knownGene=pack&position=chr17:7668421-7687490&hgFind.matches=ENST00000269305.9 )

so using **bcftools**:

```
bcftools index clinvar.vcf.gz
bcftools view clinvar.vcf.gz "chr17:7668421-7687490"
```